# How to chart a line and a fixed point in the same chart in Looker

Tags: data-visualization, looker

I want to compare precision-recall curve of my model to current rule based model precision-recall. So I want to have a chart with a line and a fixed point. Data looks like following:

| threshold | precision | recall | current precision | current recall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.01 | 0.05 | 0.93 | . 0.55 | . 0.35. |
| 0.02 | 0.07 | 0.87 | . 0.55 | . 0.35. |
| 0.03 | 0.09 | 0.81 | . 0.55 | . 0.35. |

.
.
.

Please note current precision/current recall values are constant for each row.

I want to have a line (or scatter plot) of precision recall and mark the current precision/recall point in the same chart.

Is there a way to do this in Looker?

Comment: why can't you do this in a scatter plot? what is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the chart option under the "Series" tab (see pic 1), and for current precision/recall, change the type to scatter. For the remaining dimensions( precision and recall curve), change it to an area or line chart. Also, you can even go to the "Y" tab and drag current recall and precision to the right axis if you want. The final result should be similar to pic 2.

[image]

[image]